# Adding a Vue Element to Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have my Vue element `props.item[hdr.value]` which is changable.  I print this to my webpage using `{{ props.item[hdr.value] }}`, but I am unsure how to use this value to create a dynamic `title` tag to mu link:

`<a @click="testFunc()" title="More on %%%">{{ props.item[hdr.value] }}</a>`

I have tried `' '`, `+ +`, `{ }`, `{{ }}` and various combinations around the call (and numerous Google searches) but I just cannot seem to find he rights syntax to get this to display.

Can anyone help out here please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work I got the solution, it is a derivative of the answer posted by @ricristian

`<a @click="testFunc()" :title="'More on ' + props.item[hdr.value]"></a>`

Comment: @ricristian has a cleaner solution using string interpolation though.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dynamicVariable: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <a @click="testFunc()"  :title="`More on ${dynamicVariable}`">{{ dynamicVariable }}</a>
</div>
```